# If All for One can pass quirks on to others, can he pass debilitating quirks to people that don't want them?

Tags: my-hero-academia

Since All for One can transfer quirks, can he pass along quirks to people that don't want them?

Answer (score 5):

Of course. All for One has the power to pass quirks regardless of the wishes of the receiving person.

About One For All from [fandom](https://bokunoheroacademia.fandom.com/wiki/One_For_All) :

> Long ago, a man with a Quirk that could steal other Quirks and give them away forcibly gave his seemingly Quirkless younger brother a Quirk that allowed him to stockpile power within his body.

This is the story of how One for All was born. The brother of the original All for One rejected any desire of having a quirk but his brother gave one to him regardless. So it is possible to give Quirks to people who don't want them.